# Keeps getting Routing Error.. what am I doing wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am doing the very intro course in rails, and so far have completed the following

1. Made a new rails app:  `rails new shovell` ("shovell" is the name of the app)
2. Installed all the gems and what not: `bundle install`
3. Generated a model `rails generate model Story name link`
4. Generated a controller `rails generate controller Stories index`

And now when I point to `http://localhost:3000/stories`, I get a error that says "Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/stories" "

And the following is my `routes.rb`:

```
Shovell::Application.routes.draw do
  get "stories/index"
# a bunch of comments
end
```

So I don't know what Im doing wrong, and why its not showing up the default welcome message, but rather giving me an error.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

However, if you do:

```
http://localhost:3000/stories/index
```

you may get the page, although that's not the rails way.

First thing, read and understand the [rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Then in order to fix your code, on the routing you can write

```
Shovell::Aplication.routes.draw do
  resources :stories
end
```

Or if you want custom routes instead of a rest resource

```
Shovel::Application.routes.draw do
  match "stores", to: "my_controller#my_action"
end
```

And you can also name the custom route

```
Shovel::Application.routes.draw do
  match "stores", to: "my_controller#my_action", as: :store_index
end
```

So with a name you can use the route name on your rails app

```
link_to("Store Index", store_index_path)
```

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer.  I had thought that since `index` is like the "default" go-to place of a page, it would have automatically loaded stories/index.  As to the reason why it did not, does it have to do with the fact that its `index.html.erb` rather than a plain `index.html`?

Comment: No really, you index.html.erb is converted to index.html, the extension .erb means that the file should be parsed by the ERB template system (so all those <%= %> and <%- %> are evaluated by ERB). You can also use other extensions, like index.html.haml in order to use HAML instead of ERB, and you will be later creating files like index.js.erb (so ERB is executed and execute the code on <%= =%> and then the .js file is sent to the client and executed, usually on a remote/ajax response)

Comment: Thanks for the follow up.  I noticed that with several of the guides I am going through (such as Learning Rails 3, Simply Rails, etc..), the instructions all pointed to going to the sub domain, the index.html located in that domain would the be loaded automatically.  I am currently running rails 3.2.9, and unfortunately this is no longer the case.  Was this one of the major changes from Rails 3 to Rails 3.2?

Comment: There is not any update on the rails routing between rails 3 or 3.2. Since you are doing a tutorial, would you mind uploading your code to github or bitbucket? Then let me know the url, and I'll check it out to let you know exactly what's the issue. Thx

Comment: Hi Rorra, I found in "Learning Rails 3" (the book with the horses on the cover) this bit about controllers and routing which helped explain my question: "Rails 3.x requires one more step before we can run the application.  Rails used to have default routing rules that made it easy to quickly test a controller's existance, but in Rails 3.x those rules are turned off.  To fix this... blah blah.. config/routes.rb .. uncomment `# match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)' `.  Again thanks for following up!

Answer (score 0):

You've defined a route to `/stories/index`, but you've not defined one to `/stories`, which is why this is failing.

You should define this route like this:

```
 get '/stories', :to => "stories#index"
```

For more information, see [The Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: Thanks for linking me to the guide.. I'll be sure to study in in depth.  As a follow up question, why is it then when i load localhost:3000/stories, it did not load up index.html.erb automatically?  I had thought that usually index.html served as the default go to place of a domain or subdomain.  Thanks!